# Efficient way to do lookup table in c#

Tags: c#

I have input  "Volvo-2.0","Volvo-1.8","Ford-BMax" and I would like to create a look up table that would return "Volvo" if "Volvo-2-0" or "Volvo-1.8" is input and similarly return "Ford" if "Ford-BMax" is input.

How to create look up in my Model? 
I am currently using selectlist but as I don´t want to display the selectlist what other alternative should i use for lookup in my Model?

```
public SelectList car = new SelectList(new List<object>{
                              new {text="Volvo-2.0", value="Volvo"},
                              new {text="Volvo-1.8", value="Volvo"},
                              new {text="Ford-BMax", value="Ford"}},text,value}
```

Comment: Why is your model relevant? Aren't you looking for a UI technique? Can you elaborate what exactly you're trying to do? It's unclear from your question what you want.

Comment: Couldn´t you just simply use `String.Substring` to return the substring from start until `-`?

Comment: Use dictionary for this

Comment: Why not use a dictionary to look it up?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - I thought the same but that would likely break on Mercedes-Benz

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Dictionary` because it's very fast:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("Volvo-1.8", "Volvo");
dict.Add("Volvo-2.0", "Volvo");
dict.Add("Ford-BMax", "Ford");

string brand = dict["Volvo-1.8"];
```

For more information have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary<T> will be fast, as the other answers say.

C# has a shorthand to fill them with data:

```
  Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
  {
      { "Volvo-1.8", "Volvo" },
      { "Volvo-2.0", "Volvo" },
      { "Ford-BMax", "Ford" },
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `Dictionary<,>` (like king.code says) but i would use the `TryGetValue()` method instead:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("Volvo-1.8", "Volvo");
dict.Add("Volvo-2.0", "Volvo");
dict.Add("Ford-BMax", "Ford");



string value;

if(dict.TryGetValue("Volvo-1.8", out value))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found: " + value);
}
```

The `TryGetValue()` is more safe, and avoids 2 lookups *(if you use `dict.Contains("Volvo-1.8")` and then `dict["Volvo-1.8"]`.  )*